# Custom Sort By "%%" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
|city_name|
 Shadyside
 Chalkyitsik
 Wyalusing
 Quartzsite
 Seaside
 Shawnee Mission
 Siberia
 Sibley
 Nicasio
 Lacassine
 Sicily Island
 Andalusia
 Sidell
 Sidney
 ...
 ..
 .
```

And selected with the following queries:

```
SELECT city_name FROM my_table WHERE city_name LIKE '%si%'
```

Instead of '%si%', anything can be put.

I want to sort by the words first started with 'si'.

And the output is like this:

```
|city_name|
 Siberia
 Sibley
 Sicily Island
 Sidell
 Sidney
 ... And the rest of the words that are '%si%'
```

How should this sorting(`ORDER BY`) be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple keys in the `order by` and expressions too:

```
SELECT city_name
FROM my_table
WHERE city_name LIKE '%si%'
ORDER BY (city_name LIKE 'si%') DESC, city_name;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context, with "0" for false and "1" for true.  The `DESC` puts the matches (1 = true) first.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT city_name
FROM my_table
WHERE city_name LIKE '%si%'
ORDER BY (city_name LIKE 'si%') DESC;
```